# How to make notification uncancellable/unremovable android

Tags: android, notifications

I have a player working in background. And I have notification.

Problem: when I open status bar and press Clear button, I lost my notification.
Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the Clear button to remove notifications? I'm not sure if it can be changed... And not sure if it should be changed.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Notification.Builder` you can call `setOngoing(true)` on it to make it impossoble to clear for the user. <s>If you are not using the Builder you can call `setFlag(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT, true)` on the `Notification`</s>

CORRECTION: setFlag is also part of the Builder, not of Notification

Comment: If you're not using the Builder, (a) why not, but (b) you can do something like `myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` .